# What is the type "void" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I made a `SELECT INTO` a table and then working with that table, it appears to me that it is a type of void data. This column has only nulls but I get in the popup that the column is not null.

[image]

What does void column type mean in SQL Server? since I had never seen it.

`SELECT INTO` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Item,
    NULL AS ItemDescription,
    NULL AS Marca,
    NULL AS Categoria,
    NULL AS SubCategoria
INTO 
    setup.MaestroProductos
FROM
    temp.datos
WHERE
    Item NOT IN ('servicio', 'flete') 
    AND Categoria NOT IN ('servicios', 'activos', 'activo fijo')
ORDER BY
    Item
```

Comment: Can you script out that table and post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you inserted a literal `NULL` into the table.

If you putthe below SQL into SSMS, you'll notice that `NullColumn` is defined as a "void" column by intellisense (and also interestingly as "not null"):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
SELECT NULL AS NullColumn,
       1 AS IntColumn
INTO MyTable;
GO

SELECT NullColumn,
       IntColumn
FROM dbo.MyTable;
GO
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'MyTable';

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

[image]

This is because, within the same session, SSMS can't derive the datatype of a literal `NULL` (or even it's Nullability); however the column created will end up being a nullable `int`.

If you run the SQL up to and including the `INTO` statement and then create a new connection and check the data type (after refreshing intellisense), then you'll notice it shows as a nullable `int`:

[image]

To respond to the OP's comment *"Because in the designer I defined the column as an integer type and in the pop up of the image as a void type."* I cannot replicate this behaviour. I can only do this if I don't define the data type. If the OP really *is* defining the type, then we need their script to replicate the problem.

[image]

Comment: So it is really Intellisense's fault to create these types of data? Because in the designer I defined the column as an integer type and in the pop up of the image as a void type.

Comment: Considering we don't have the `INTO` script, @ChristopherThompson, I can't give a comment. I didn't define `NullColumn` as a `int` in the above though (but, if I do, I can't replicate the behaviour).

Comment: *"I defined the column as an integer type"*; that isn't true at all @ChristopherThompson. You have `null as ItemDescription`; where does that define the column as an `int`? This answer therefore exactly shows you why you have the datatype `void`. Seems my crystal ball worked today. :)